# Drawing a texture in opengl in C

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I tried loading a texture with SOIL and drawing it with a function I created which gets a texture and many details of it - and then draws it.

The problem is - that when I draw it - the location of the picture changes when the width and height changes. I want it not to - I want it to choose the left bottom point and draw from there as in this painting : http://postimg.org/image/kalv23v3p/ (forgive me for my lousy computer painting skill) so I can - for example - make an HP bar that can decrease and increase with the same X and Y and stay the same position. The problem (according to my understanding of the functions) is in `glTranslatef` :P

```
 void DrawImage(char filename,
                       int xx,
                       int yy,
                       int ww,
                       int hh,
                       int angle,
                       int xp,
                       int yp) 
{
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, filename);

  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(xx + (ww / 2),yy + (hh / 2),0.0);
  glRotatef(angle,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  glTranslatef(-(xx + (ww / 2) + xp),-(yy + (hh / 2) + yp),0.0);

  // Draw a textured quad
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(xx,yy);
  glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(xx,yy + hh);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(xx + ww,yy + hh);
  glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(xx + ww,yy);

  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glPopMatrix();

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPopMatrix();

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glEnd();
}
```

when the `filename` is actually the texture itself (GLuint usually).
Basically the function is from [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/174197-how-do-i-draw-2d-textures-on-screen) but I changed it so it'll get all of these parameters.
Any idea how to solve my problem and make the code work how I want it to?

Comment: You can't call `glDisable`, `glPopMatrix`, or `glMatrixMode` between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. It will cause an error (which I'm guessing you don't check for).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Really ? .-. The code ran perfectly and I drew multiple textures

Comment: If you're not checking for errors with `glGetError` then you won't notice it. Either way, they aren't doing anything and should be removed.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Okay, thanks a bunch :)
Any idea how can I fix the problem ? :P

Comment: Without them in the middle it won't paint it well, any idea what the problem may be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess ww and hh are your with and height params...

With glTranslatef you move everything around if you use ww and hh for it's params. Try to change

```
glTranslatef(xx + (ww / 2),yy + (hh / 2),0.0);
```

To

```
glTranslatef(xx, yy, 0.0);
```

and

```
glTranslatef(-(xx + (ww / 2) + xp),-(yy + (hh / 2) + yp),0.0);
```

To

```
glTranslatef(-(xx + xp),-(yy + yp),0.0);
```

Now if you want to resize don't use glTranslatef. Use **glScalef** to resize.

Comment: LOTS AND LOTS OF THANKS. Thank you very much.